# Does the "Executed DbCommand" logging statement in .NET EF Core includes latency?

Tags: c#, .net, database, logging, entity-framework-core

I have a question regarding the "Executed DbCommand" statements output by the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging mechanism in a .NET project utilising EF Core. Namely, does the time logged in this way refer only to how long it takes to perform that particular operation within the database itself, or does it also include latency that occurs from communication with the remote database?

A follow-up question - if the time logged **does not** include latency, what would be the best approach to logging the operation taking latency into consideration?

I tried writing such an interceptor in order to capture the entire duration of the operation, latency included:

```cs
    public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(
        DbContextEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var interceptionResult = await base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
        stopwatch.Stop();

        _logger.LogInformation($"SaveChangesAsync took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        return interceptionResult;
    }
```

The elapsed time logged in this case is consistently 0ms, whereas the "Executed DbCommand" reports ~7ms. I expected the time logged by the interceptor to be greater than what the "Executed DbCommand" reports back, however since it's 0ms it's not only not working properly but probably not at all for some reason.

Comment: You need to stop the watch after `SaveChangesAsync` not saving..

Comment: What does StopWatch.IsHighResolution return?

Comment: @Eldar thanks for the idea, I think I managed to get something done. I'll double check and post the code if it works.

Comment: @Ralf from the docs: "Indicates whether the timer is based on a high-resolution performance counter." - did I use that? I can't remember TBH...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, attempts to find an answer in the EF Core docs were unsuccessful. For that reason I tried to measure the time it takes from starting the database operation to its finish, and compare it to the time logged by the "Executed DbCommand" statements.

This is the interceptor class I wrote:

```
public class SaveChangesTimeInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    private readonly ILogger<SaveChangesTimeInterceptor> _logger;
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    public SaveChangesTimeInterceptor(ILogger<SaveChangesTimeInterceptor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(
        DbContextEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(
        SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData,
        int result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        _logger.LogDebug(LogEventIds.EXECUTION_TIME, "Executed '{action}' in {elapsedMilliseconds}ms.", "SaveChangesAsync", _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return await base.SavedChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The class is thread-safe as a new instance of the interceptor is created for each new request. Also, the time elapsed varied but it was always significantly longer than the result of the "Executed DbCommand" log statements so I concluded that the "Executed DbCommand" logs do not include latency caused by contacting the external services.